# passing a textbox value to a javascript function asp.net

Tags: javascript

I am having a little difficulty with this one. Trying to pass a textBox value to a javascript function and get undefined instead.

Advice perhaps on how I can get this variable to the function

```
<input type="image" runat="server" id="btnSearchFunction" src="Images/searchIcon.png" name="image" onclick="SearchContent();" width="16" height="20" />
<input type="hidden" name="searchValue" value="<%#txtSearch.Value %>" />
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtSearch" name="searchValue" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Search ..."/>
```

and this is the function I am trying to pass it to

```
function SearchContent() {
    var txtBoxValue = $(this).parent().find("input[name='searchValue']").val();
    alert(txtBoxValue);
}
```

Comment: You are right, sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something more direct:

```
var txtBoxValue = $('#txtSearch').val();
alert(txtBoxValue);
```

Comment: this will find by ID, is it working for name Attribute as well?

Comment: @Damith, notice the markup, the ***id*** of the text box is `txtSearch`.

Comment: from the question `input[name='searchValue']` , OP try to find input with name `searchValue`, I'm not the Down Voter :)

Comment: @Damith, and I'm letting the OP know there is a **much** better way. An `id` is specified, use it. Working up the DOM trying to find something then below is messy at best, especially when not necessary.

Comment: @Arianule, not a problem friend. I'm glad I could be of assistance!